# How to display a part of a shape in Orchard CMS

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, razor, orchardcms

in the Layout.cshtml file in own created admin theme for orchard that it contains the below code for display admin UI's header:

```
 @if (Model.Header != null) {
   <div id="header" role="banner">
      @Zone(Model.Header)
   </div>
 }
```

Considering that the `Model.Header` contains two part for display: `User.cshtml` and `Header.cshtml`. now what i want to do is to perevent display the header, and in other word i want to display just `User.cshtml` part existing in `Model.Header` shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bertrand's answer is spot on for a front-end theme but as you are referring to a custom admin theme I took at look at `Layout.cshtml` in TheAdmin.

Just before the snippet you posted there are the following lines which build up the header and footer zones:

```
Model.Header.Add(Display.Header());

Model.Header.Add(Display.User(CurrentUser: WorkContext.CurrentUser));
Model.Footer.Add(Display.OrchardVersion());
```

Remove the first line and the header zone will just contain the User shape.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't add it in the first place. The code that adds the user shape to the header zone is right there in the layout.cshtml template. I don't know what theme you're using but in the theme machine, it's this line of code:

```
WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.User(), "10")
```